# Box Jelly animation to Collada dae

Tags: animation, collada, dae

I need animated box, so it jiggles like jelly. I tried everything I found, but I can not get the solution. I need to export it to .dae (collada), so I would be able to add it to Xcode - SceneKit. I tried to animate it by simulating physics, but collada does not support that, so I tried to animate it with skeleton aswell, but blender collada export does not support skeletal skin animation, so that also does not work. Could you please anyone help me find any solution for that?

I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Blender can export rigged mesh to collada. It works fine. Also supports the shape keys.

Comment: @FFeller Could you be more specific please? I can not get it working.

Comment: If I create a rigged mesh and animate it and export it to dae, then reimport. It works fine.